# How to display the title and subtitle of a chart (at the top or bottom) with "vue-google-charts" (from devstark)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, linechart

Using
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-charts

It doesn't show's the title at all. Is there a possibility to display it at the top of or under the chart?

tryed to give a "display=true" with the option "title" ... to format it in '' and ""

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <GChart     
            :settings="{packages: ['bar']}"    
            type="LineChart"
            :data="chartData"
            :options="chartOptions"
            style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"
        />


        <GChart
            type="ColumnChart"
            :data="chartData"
            :options="chartOptions"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import VueGoogleCharts from 'vue-google-charts'
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                // Array will be automatically processed with visualization.arrayToDataTable function
                chartData: [
                ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
                ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
                ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
                ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
                ['2017', 1030, 540, 350],
                ['2018', 2000, 1, 1]
                ],
                chartOptions:{
                    chart: {
                    title: 'Company Performance',
                    subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

I want the title "Company Performance" and subtitle "Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017" of the chart showing up (over the chart or under it).